# tensorflow - attribute within a node does not initialize

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to share variable ".threshold" across RELU nodes. the below syntax returns the following error:

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value relu/weights

it seems that variable w, defined in the relu() function, is not initialized.

i attempted two fixes (neither works):

1.) Adding line:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

does not work most likely because W is defined within the function thus is not GLOBAL

2.) modifying session call to:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(relu.w.initializer.run())
    sess.run(output)
```

which results in the following error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'w'

How can i change it to make it run?

```
def relu(X):
    threshold = tf.get_variable("threshold", shape=(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    w_shape = (int(X.get_shape()[1]), 1)
    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(w_shape), name="weights")
    b = tf.Variable(0.0, name="bias")
    z = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w), b, name="z")
    return tf.maximum(z, threshold, name="max")

relus = []
for relu_index in range(5):
    with tf.variable_scope("relu", reuse=(relu_index >= 1)) as scope:
        relus.append(relu(X))

output = tf.add_n(relus, name="output")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(output)
```

Comment: In the second codeblock, you should have the line `sess.run(init)` before `sess.run(output)`.

Comment: yes, the values were not initialized yet. it fixed the issue